# Oracle Apex Data Generator

Tags: oracle-apex, data-generation

Using Oracle Apex 22.2, I can't seem to work out some basic formula's using the oracle apex data generator. With no error handling, and very little documentation, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax. Here are some examples of what I would like to achieve:

1. Generate a truncated date between a start and end date. Make sure it's distinct so the date can only appear once in the data set.
2. Use a case/if statement that uses the value of one column to determine the value of another column.
3. Generate a date based off of another date contained in the same record (date 2 = date 1 + 1 day)

Any further documentation on how to make the actual formula and built in components work would be appreciated. Something as simple as `trunc({createddate})` throws an error. All I can find so far has been vague and doesn't get into the details of syntax and data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

For bullet point 1: I don't think that is possible, this is a row generator, you're asking for a functionality across rows.
Bullet point 2 and 3. I'm not sure what syntaxes are allowed, the doc is indeed very basic. However you can create a pl/sql function and reference that so I'd go ahead and give that a try (this could be pretty buggy).

I would solve issue 1 with a custom script and 2/3 either by adding a virtual column to your table or a custom script too.

Comment: 1. Solid logic       
2/3. They have the OOB formula field where in the examples it references other columns. Something like this should be possible, as the whole reason they built it would be to avoid writing custom scripts to insert test data. The internet seems to be particularly dry on this feature.

Either way appreciate your input!